# Facebook Like - Fanpage not current URL with API

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

Currently I'm hitting the API through the JS SDK.  What I am trying to do is accomplish is having a like button on **my website**.  But rather than liking the URL you are on..like the fan page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

With the iframe version: you would assign the `href` value to the URL you'd want to like. In your case, the url of the facebook fan page.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOURURLHERE&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&amp;locale=en_GB" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:75px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Just make sure you escape the characters in the url correctly. For example:

http://www.facebook.com/yourpage

would become:

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fyourpage